# Words should be printed one below the other but printed in one line

Tags: python

Result required:

> Give a word: sausage
>
> Give a number: 6
>
> sausage
>
> sausage
>
> sausage
>
> sausage
>
> sausage
>
> sausage

Result getting:

> Give a word: sausage
>
> Give a number: 6
>
> sausagesausagesausagesausagesausagesausage

```
def repeat_this(s, n):
    print (s * n)

s = input("Give a word: ")
n = int(input("Give a number: "))
repeat_this(s, n)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `'\n'.join` to join strings together with newlines. In this case, we need a list containing `n` copies of `s`, which can be achieved by writing `[s] * n`:

```py
def repeat_this(s, n):
    print('\n'.join([s] * n))
```